# Unable to build Tensorflow from source MacOS High Sierra

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I've followed all the steps in the [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#PrepareMac). Except I built it using:

```
$ bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=- msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --config=opt -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

And during `./config` I've set the right paths and disabled Google Cloud Platform, Hadoop, XLA, VERBS, OpenCL, CUDA, MPI support.

Hardware:

- Macbook Pro 13 inch (mid 2014)
- CPU: Intel Core i5 (4278U)
- RAM: 8GB

Software:

- High Sierra (10.13.2)
- Clang Version: clang-900.0.39.2
- Bazel Version: 0.9.0
- Conda Version: 4.4.3
- Python: 3.6.3

All the packages are upto date. This worked perfectly fine 2 months ago on this machine. For some strange reasons it doesn't build anymore now. I'm just posting a part of the error list here:

> WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: opt
>
> ERROR: Skipping 'msse4.1': no such target '//:msse4.1': target 'msse4.1' not declared in package '' defined by /Users/rakshithgb/Documents/Tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD
>
> WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
>
> ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rakshithgb/fde7bc60972656b0c2db4fd0b79e24fb/external/com_googlesource_code_re2/BUILD:96:1: First argument of 'load' must be a label and start with either '//', ':', or '@'. Use --incompatible_load_argument_is_label=false to temporarily disable this check.
>
> ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rakshithgb/fde7bc60972656b0c2db4fd0b79e24fb/external/com_googlesource_code_re2/BUILD:98:1: name 're2_test' is not defined (did you mean 'ios_test'?)
>
> ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_rakshithgb/fde7bc60972656b0c2db4fd0b79e24fb/external/com_googlesource_code_re2/BUILD:100:1: name 're2_test' is not defined (did you mean 'ios_test'?)

And it ends like this:

> ERROR: /Users/rakshithgb/Documents/Tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:550:1: Target '@local_config_sycl//sycl:using_sycl' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/core/kernels:debug_ops'
>
> WARNING: errors encountered while analyzing target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': it will not be built
>
> INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (203 packages loaded).
>
> INFO: Found 0 targets...
>
> ERROR: command succeeded, but there were errors parsing the target pattern
>
> INFO: Elapsed time: 12.763s, Critical Path: 0.02s
>
> FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

Has anyone else had this issue? How do I fix it? I've uploaded the entire error log on GitHub Tensorflow issue page. [#15622](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15622)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it looks like the new bazel version isn't compatible with the current Tensorflow release. It looks like the fix will be issued in the next release. According to this thread on GitHub - [#15492](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15492)

The temporary fix that worked for me was to build it using `--incompatible_load_argument_is_label=false` in the bazel command. So my build command now looks like this:

```
$ bazel build --config=opt --incompatible_load_argument_is_label=false //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```